# CSS menu item bullets using pseudo elements - indent second line of text

Tags: css

I have this vertical menu. I'm using pseudo elements to ceate bullets. If the menu item text is long, it breaks into two lines, which is fine, except that the second line is not indented so that it lines up with the first line.
How can I fix that?

html:

```
<div class="leftmenu">
  <ul class="sidebar-items">
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Indent second line indent second line indent second line</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
}

ul li a:before {
  content: "*";
  float: left;
  line-height: 11px;
  margin: 5px 7px 0 0;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1hnueso7/3/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add padding to the li elements, and position the pseudo element absolutely.

```css
.leftmenu {
  width: 300px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

ul li a:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: "*";
  line-height: 11px;
  margin: 5px 7px 0 0;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftmenu">
  <ul class="sidebar-items">
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Indent second line indent second line indent second line</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `margin` and `text-indent`. Apply a negative `text-indent` to the list item, and a `margin` to the `pseudoelement`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/h5r9rr04/1/)

```css
.leftmenu {
  width: 300px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -1em;
}

ul li a:before {
  content: "*";
  float: left;
  line-height: 11px;
  margin: 5px 7px 0 0;
  margin-right: 1em;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftmenu">
  <ul class="sidebar-items">
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Indent second line indent second line indent second line</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the **left margin** of your asterisk and pull it to the left by around a character's length. So your **ul li a:before** will look like this:

```
ul li a:before {
  content: "*";
  float: left;
  line-height: 11px;
  margin: 5px 7px 0 -15px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Now if that shifts your list item from the position you intended you can always add some margin left or some padding left in your ul li:

```
ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```